# Python3 Flask - missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have very simple python code to access Amazon Simple Queue Service. But I get

```
   builtins.TypeError
TypeError: get_queue() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

My code:

```
class CloudQueue(object):

    conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("eu-west-1",
        aws_access_key_id="abc",
        aws_secret_access_key="abc")


    @app.route('/get/<name>')  
    def get_queue(self, name):

        if(name != None):
            queue = self.conn.get_queue(str(name)) <--------- HERE
        return conn.get_all_queues()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cq = CloudQueue()
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Comment: And indeed, `self` is not defined; your method doesn't have the parameter at all. You cannot register a method on a class in any case, because the method isn't bound to an instance when you are registering it with the decorator.

Comment: I get builtins.TypeError
TypeError: get_queue() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

when I add self to def get_queue(self,name)

Comment: @user2988649: exactly, that's what I meant by *You cannot register a method*. The decorator runs *there and then* before the class object is created, so you are registering just the function, not a method bound to an instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot register methods as routes; at the time the decorator runs the class is still being defined and all you registered is the unbound function object. Since it is not bound to an instance there is no `self` to pass in.

Do not use a class here; create the connection anew for each request:

```
@app.route('/get/<name>')  
def get_queue(name):
    conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("eu-west-1",
        aws_access_key_id="abc",
        aws_secret_access_key="abc")

    queue = conn.get_queue(name)
    return 'some response string'
```

You could set it as a global but then you need to make sure you re-create the connection on the first request (so it continues to work even when using a WSGI server using child processes to handle requests):

```
@app.before_first_request()
def connect_to_boto():
    global conn
    conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("eu-west-1",
        aws_access_key_id="abc",
        aws_secret_access_key="abc")

@app.route('/get/<name>')  
def get_queue(name):
    queue = conn.get_queue(name)
    return 'some response string'
```

Use this only if you are sure that `boto` connection objects are thread-safe.